# Can't connect to mySql db on Google cloud using JDBC

Tags: mysql, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, jdbc, hikaricp

I am trying to connect to my mysql DB on google cloud from my android app via an emulator. but I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server
```

The server is up and running (I can connect from mySql Workbench). I tried lots of things including  adding the necessary permissions to the manifest file and using other methods like Hikari, but nothing worked. Here is my code:

```
    private const val DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://<local-host>/<db-name>?connectTimeout=30000"
    private const val DB_USER = "username"
    private const val DB_PASSWORD = "password"

    fun getConnection(): Connection {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    }
```

What else can be the problem?

**Update:** I tried it from a physical device instead of an emulator, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Where is running your code? Where is running your database? Why are you using a localhost for your database? Can you share more about your design?

Comment: My code is running on an emulator via Android Studio. My database is on google cloud. Isn't using localhost the default way to connect to my db on cloud?

Comment: Yes, localhost is one way to access your Cloud database ONLY if you have the Cloud SQL proxy on your machine. It's a proxy that listen on the local host and forward the request to your database in the Cloud.